# How to access DNG file creation date from Windows Explorer

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-explorer, cygwin

I would like to access the creation date of a DNG file, SomeImage.DNG. In Windows Explorer, under View > Details, the "Date" column lists the correct creation date, which I happen to know. But when I try to access the creation date from different tools on the command line, I get the modification date which is when I copied and unzipped the file. I only get the modification date from the Windows command line CMD using "dir /T:C SomeImage.DNG", and using bash from Cygwin, "stat -c "%w" SomeImage.DNG". Using "exiftool -CreateDate SomeImage.DNG" is too slow because the file is large.

From the command line, how can I access the "Date" that is displayed in Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Dare` property in **Explorer** ([System.ItemDate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props-system-itemdate)) is dynamic; the date it displays can vary based on filetype and whether or not metadata is available. For insurance,  A `.jpg` file will map `Date` to `Date Taken` *if available `, but otherwise default to the creation date from the file-sysrem.

I'm not familiar with `.DNG` files, so questions are:.

- Do the files have additional date properties encoded in metadata?
- If you display *all* available date columns in **Explorer**, which one matches the `Date` column?

If you need to access extended properties, you need to use a com object. Easy in **PowerShell**, but not cmd.exe.

I can post**PowerShell** code if you like...

Comment: Crazily, the Explorer "Date" column is several hours earlier than the Explorer "Date Created" and "Date Modified" columns , which are identical down to the minute (seconds are not displayed), plus they are the same as the FileModDate, DateTime, and PreviewDateTime tags in the DNG file. Of all these flavors of dates, only the Explorer "Date" seems to put the DNG images in the order that the photos were taken in. 
So still not clear what Explorer "Date" is, but thanks for the PowerShell tip on accessing it.

Comment: When I right click in Windows Explorer on the file to look at Properties, the correct time is called "Date Taken", which is earlier than "Date created" and "Date modified". It's a Windows-specific date based on the ["DateTimeOriginal"](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/Shortcuts.html) tag in the DNG file, which can be extracted from the command line using
`exiftool -DateTimeOriginal SomeImage.dng`. The command is reasonably fast even on a large DNG file.